# Round to places to 0 c#

Tags: c#

I want to round a decimal number with 2 places to an integer.

> Ex: 3.772.002,47 --- decimal
>       3.772.003

Im using this code but with no success:

```
ssOut = Math.Round(ssIn, ssDecimal, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

Anyone can help me?
Thanks.

Comment: Why would 3772002,47 round to 377200**3**?

Comment: There is a `Math.Ceiling()` if you want to round up.

Comment: I'm confused. Your `.` is thousands separator and `,` is decimal separator. But when you round it, your `3772002.47` will be `3772003`. Do you want to round it up with `Ceiling`?

Comment: What does "with no success" mean? Do you get an exception or does the returned value not meet your expectation? If the latter, what *was* returned?

Comment: because if i round 1 place 3772002,5 and now i get 3772003

Comment: Corak  the result is always 3772002

Comment: @userprofile1 you need to specify strategy - you want to round to the nearest integer that is highter than current? Or nearest less? You have used `AwayFromZero`. Are you aware what does it mean?

Comment: `3772002` is the correct way to round `3772002.47` to a value with no decimal places. - there is no intermediate step of rounding it to *one* decimal place.

Comment: @userprofile1:- Try this: `int ssOut = (int)Math.Ceiling(ssIn);`

Comment: Corak thanks, then the solution is round to 1 place and then 0 places

Comment: If that is the strategy you *want*... but I've never heard of an application where that kind of rounding would be considered correct. --- just to be sure, you still want `3772002.44` to be rounded to `3772002`, right?

Comment: Corak i know but is what i have to do :P thanks for help

Comment: Usually for rounding only the immediate next decimal place is to be considered. So even `x.4999999999` would *still* be rounded to `x` and *not* `x+1`. The `MidpointRounding` is *only* relevant for the exact case of `x.5` because then it depends on the application if you want to round towards or away from zero or switch it up based on if `x` is even or odd (bankers rounding; the default).

Answer (score 1):

You need cast a result to `int`:

```
var ssOut = (int)Math.Round(ssIn,
                            0, /* zero because you want to cast to integer - no fraction part is needed */
                            MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

You can do the same with the following overload:

```
var ssOut = (int)Math.Round(ssIn, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero);
```

But it looks like you need `Math.Ceiling` - like it is said in comments below questions.

Comment: no because ceiling round always up and i only want round when decimal place is >= 5

Comment: @userprofile1 so what is the problem? In case you presented, f.e `3 772 002,47 ` should be round to `3 772 002` , because the fraction is < 5.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your input may be a string.  First use Float.Parse() or Double.Parse() to convert string to number before rounding.